# How to sync NTP without app or db downtime?

Tags: linux, ntp, ntpd

How can we sync the ntp gradually, without harming the timestamps in running application and database? My clock is 12 minutes ahead

OS: Oracle Linux 6.4

NTP:

ntpdate-4.2.4p8-3.el6.x86_64

ntp-4.2.4p8-3.el6.x86_64

Comment: Whatever you do, don't use `ntpdate`

Comment: If this is a production system, don't try it here first. Use a test system to confirm to yourself what's going on

Comment: once I used [this solution](https://askubuntu.com/a/256004/283843) to sync the data&time, but I was not on production

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `ntdate`, despite warning against it (e.g. if you use your own LAN NTP server, nobody from the outside will spoof the time).

The important parameter is `ntpdate -B`,  to force slow adjusting (it will be slow, but it will drift there eventually). And you have to stop your local ntp daemon first, if it is running.

Comment: Does `-B` work for offsets in excess of 10 minutes?

Comment: @roaima Yes. I've seen it work with an offset of 5 years (SoC workstation without RTC rebooted while the internet was down and ifup scripts failed to reach the ntp server); though of course it would take many months to sync the time...

Comment: Considerably easier then my approach then :-)

Comment: @RadovanGarabík thanks;)

Answer (score 0):

**Disclaimer: I don't have Oracle Linux installed. Try this on a disposable test machine with an equally wrong clock before it goes anywhere near your production environment.**

NTP can synchronise clocks that are up to 10 minutes wrong. However, you've stated that yours is approximately 12.5 minutes fast. The easy route is to shut down the machine, reset the clock, and then restart it (if necessary, waiting until reality has caught up with your clock's old time, so there's no overlap in timestamps). I'm assuming you can't do this, because it's so obvious I would have expected you to have taken this route already.

So, we need to look at alternatives.

Taking a suggestion from the [NTP FAQ](http://www.ntp.org/ntpfaq/NTP-s-config-tricks.htm#AEN4252) you could try this

1. Create `/etc/ntp.conf` with the following content

   ```
    server 127.127.0.1
    fudge  127.127.0.1 stratum 10
    driftfile /var/lib/ntp/ntp.drift
   ```
2. Create a fake drift file, `/var/lib/ntp/ntp.drift` with this content, making sure that it is owned and readable/writeable by the `ntp` user account

   ```
    -500.000
   ```
3. Install the NTP daemon (`ntpd`), and verify that it has started. Ensure that it has not overwritten `/etc/ntp.conf` and `/var/lib/ntp/ntp.drift` with its default settings. If it has, stop the daemon, rewrite the files once more, and restart it.
4. Check every few days to see how the clock is slowing. Leave everything until it has reached less than ten minutes off reality - a process that may take several weeks - and do not perform the next step until then
5. Stop the NTP daemon (`ntpd`), remove the entire NTP application, remove `/etc/ntp.conf` and `/var/lib/ntp/ntp.drift`, and then reinstall the NTP daemon once more. It should automatically create the missing `/etc/ntp.conf` with suitable default values. If necessary, amend these appropriately to ensure that your system's clock remains accurate.